# Wordpress do_shortcode not working when new user is created

Tags: wordpress, user-registration

I am currently using Groups plugin and I want a new user is assigned automatically to a group when it is created. $groupName prints out loggedin user's group(contributor) and when a contributor creates a new user (subscriber), subscriber should have the same group as contributor. Debugger showed $groupName correctly, but the do_shortcode part does not work. Do you have any idea?

```
add_action( 'user_register', array($this, 'create_user'), 10, 1 );

function create_user($user_id) {

global $wpdb;

//Get current user's group id from database

$getValue = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_id , wp_groups_group.group_id, wp_groups_user_group.group_id, name  FROM  wp_groups_group, wp_groups_user_group WHERE wp_groups_group.group_id =  wp_groups_user_group.group_id");

$currentUser = wp_get_current_user();
$currentUserID = $currentUser->ID;
$groupID = "";
$groupName = "";
foreach ($getValue as $key => $value) {
    if ($currentUserID == $value->user_id  && $value->group_id > 1) {
        $groupID = $value->group_id;
        $groupName = $value->name;

    }else{
    }
}

do_shortcode('[groups_join group="'.$groupName.'"]');

}
```

Comment: should'nt do_shortcode be used as echo?

echo do_shortcode('');

Comment: I have tried that before asking but it did not work. :/